# flutter initstate() method error dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method

Tags: flutter, dart

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
if (mounted) {
setState(() {
parameterValueNotifier = widget.parameterValueNotifier;
parameterValueNotifier.onValueChanged = _onParameterValueChange;
parameterValue = parameterValueNotifier.value;
});
}
} 
void _onParameterValueChange(String newValue) {
Navigator.of(context).push(
MaterialPageRoute(
builder: (_) => AnotherPage(parameterValue: newValue),
),
);
}
```

call method _onParameterValueChange show error :

```
I/flutter (25975): Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
I/flutter (25975): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
I/flutter (25975): To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
I/flutter (25975): #0      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4334:9)
```

My splash page is of the StatelessWidget type, in which I send information to the MYpage class using the ChangeNotifierProvider.

Comment: this initState is in splash page?

Comment: no 
home: MyHomePage(parameterValueNotifier: parameterValueNotifier)
in myhomepage class
home is splash creen

Comment: Try to use a global context key for the navigator. This is probably the issue.

Comment: Otherwise try to remove the setState around your stuff inside initState and move super.initState(); to the end of the function.

Comment: `@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    parameterValueNotifier = widget.parameterValueNotifier;
    parameterValueNotifier.onValueChanged = _onParameterValueChange;
    parameterValue = parameterValueNotifier.value;
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      checkForUpdate();
    }
    _isConnected = false;
    checkInternetConnection();
  }`